# How do I run ng serve locally after ng build

Tags: angular

I use angular 4, i build a new package with this command ng build --prod
How to test on a local this new package in folder dist/package

Comment: With the command `ng build` do you build the package or your project ?

Comment: There is an extension in VsCode called live server that can create and serve you static files with just one click..

Answer (score 0):

**You can use `angular-http-server` to serve dist in `local`**

Follow below step:

1.`npm install -g angular-http-server`  //install

2.`cd /path/to/site` //move to dist folder

3.`angular-http-server` //run this command

And browse to `localhost:8080`